# From MS SQL to MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql-server

I use Migration Wizard in Workbench for convert my databadse from MS SQL to mySQL.
Settings in Source Selection:

```
Database System = Microsoft SQL SERVER
Connectiton Method = ODBC (native)
```

Test Connection was successful

Settings in Target Selection:

```
Stored Connection : Local instanse Mysql57 
Connectiton Method : Standart TCP/IP
```

And Test Connection was successful too, but in Feth Shemas List all process stopped. no progress and messege log is empty.What can I done to fix it?

[image]

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: Why Migration don't start ?

Comment: I'm not sure how any can possibly answer this reliably based on only two pictures and no other information. I could be wrong, though.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you are using the correct feature for what you need, sometimes it may be confusing.

- **Database migrations - *enables migrations from Microsoft SQL Server, Sybase ASE and PostgreSQL.***
- **Migration project management - *allows migrations to be configured, copied, edited, executed and scheduled.***

For more information http://www.mysql.com/products/workbench/migrate/